# Incoming messages are treated as outgoing in Atmosphere

Tags: java, atmosphere

I have a problem concerning receiving messages (I use `@ManagedService`). I use the same connection to send and receive messages between browser and my Java program. I can see that all the messages pass through `ManagedAtmosphereHandler.message(AtmosphereResource resource, Object o)` method.

If it is an incoming message, Atmosphere iterates through all methods marked `@Message`. Then it tries to find a decoder and eventually invokes correct method.

For outgoing messages, Atmosphere retrieves invoked method. It does so by getting `localAttribute` named "`ManagedAtmosphereHandler`" (name of current class). It is present only for outgoing messages. Then the message is encoded and send to browser.

The problem is, sometimes `invokedMethod` is set for incoming messages. It results in treating my incoming messages as outgoing. Does anybody know why it happens? My outgoing messages are scheduled and I suppose that's the reason why it happens, but I'm not sure. When are these `localAttributes` set and what are they for?

Answer (score 0):

I updated Atmosphere 2.3.0-RC6 to 2.3.0 and it works like a charm now.